tls_client_err-15 when trying to connecting Pico W to server
I'm trying to make my Raspberry Pi Pico W report to a new server, however the Pico will not connect to the server and gives me the error code tls_client_err-15 when trying to connect.
The reporting port in the server is open, which makes me believe the problem is not with the firewall. All the config files are the same as when it worked on the old server, except for the randomly generated R10 certificate.
I originally thought the problem was with the certificates. For the old server, I had let's encrypt X1 and R3 and for the new server I have X1 and R10. After updating the Pico with R10 instead of R3, I still get the error. When trying to make the sensor trust only X1, the connection still fails.
The server is TLS 1.3 but the Pico has TLS 1.2, this worked with the old server. When defining TLS 1.3 for the Pico as well as 1.2, I don't get the error code but the Pico does its restart rutine as programmed when failiing to establish connection.
